# System Account Vs. Site Collection Administrators

Tags: 2010, site-collection, administration, user-accounts

I have SharePoint 2010 Server. I have put myself as a Site Collection Administrator.

Somehow someone was able to check out a document with the System Account. I, thinking that I had just as much permission as the System Account, went to check in the file, but was not presented with the option.

I had to log in with the system account to check the document back in.

**How do I get my Site Collection Administrator account to have the same amount of permission levels as the System Account** ... without actually using the System Account as my log in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is add the Site Collection Administrator account as a Farm Administrator, which is essentially what the System Account is as far as permissions are concerned.

Comment: I have already had the accounts in the Farm Administrator list and then added them to the site Collection Administrator (some were missing). Still, I am not able to check back in a document that was checked out by the "System Account". Any other thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: I should state that adding them as the Site Collection Admin worked for their permissions, but the system checked out file is still an issue.